# Animation issue on Roblox Studio

Tags: lua, roblox

I made a button that triggers an animation for the player, but it only works for me. My friend says she could press the button but the animation does not activate. I simply used the guide on [proximty prompt](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/onboarding/scripting-avatar-animations/2). Someone told me it's got nothing to do with being a localscript, so I'm at loss now

Script below is placed under StarterPlayer > StarterPlayerScripts

```
local Players = game:GetService("Players")

local player = Players.LocalPlayer
local character = player.Character
if not character or not character.Parent then
    character = player.CharacterAdded:Wait()
end

local humanoid = character:WaitForChild("Humanoid")
local Animator = humanoid:WaitForChild("Animator")

local shockButton = workspace.ShockButton.Button
local proximityPrompt = shockButton.ProximityPrompt

local shockAnimation = Instance.new("Animation")
shockAnimation.AnimationId = "rbxassetid://9349455501"

local shockAnimationTrack = Animator:LoadAnimation(shockAnimation)

shockAnimationTrack.Priority = Enum.AnimationPriority.Action
shockAnimationTrack.Looped = false

local function onShockTrigger(player)
    
    shockAnimationTrack:Play()
    humanoid.WalkSpeed = 0
    shockAnimationTrack.Stopped:Wait()
    humanoid.WalkSpeed = 16
end

proximityPrompt.Triggered:Connect(onShockTrigger)
```

Comment: Why nobody is answering?

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't with your code, it is where it is located. Changes made to the world in LocalScripts are not replicated to other players, they only show up for that player. So, because you are telling the animation to play in a LocalScript, only that player sees the animation.

The easy fix is to move the animation code into a server Script, and move the Script into ServerScriptService or the Workspace. ProximityPrompts tell you which player interacted with it, so you can find the player's character model based on that.

```
local shockButton = workspace.ShockButton.Button
local proximityPrompt = shockButton.ProximityPrompt

local shockAnimation = Instance.new("Animation")
shockAnimation.AnimationId = "rbxassetid://9349455501"

local function onShockTrigger(player)
    -- get the animator
    local character = player.Character
    if not character or not character.Parent then
        character = player.CharacterAdded:Wait()
    end
    local humanoid = character:WaitForChild("Humanoid")
    local Animator = humanoid:WaitForChild("Animator")

    -- configure the animation
    local shockAnimationTrack = Animator:LoadAnimation(shockAnimation)
    shockAnimationTrack.Priority = Enum.AnimationPriority.Action
    shockAnimationTrack.Looped = false

    -- play the animation
    shockAnimationTrack:Play()
    humanoid.WalkSpeed = 0
    shockAnimationTrack.Stopped:Wait()
    humanoid.WalkSpeed = 16
end

proximityPrompt.Triggered:Connect(onShockTrigger)
```